# How can I make the following object?

Tags: java

I am new in java. So , I am trying to make asteroid game project.I have this point class

```
  class Point implements Cloneable {
     double x,y;
     public Point(double inX, double inY) { x = inX; y = inY; }

  public Point clone() {
      return new Point(x, y);
   }
   }
```

and the polygon class which takes an array of points,point and integer.
     class Polygon {
        private Point[] shape;   // An array of points.
        public Point position;   // The offset mentioned above.
        public double rotation; // Zero degrees is due east.

```
       public Polygon(Point[] inShape, Point inPosition, double inRotation) {
           shape = inShape;
           position = inPosition;
           rotation = inRotation;

    // First, we find the shape's top-most left-most boundary, its origin.
    Point origin = shape[0].clone();
        for (Point p : shape) {
        if (p.x < origin.x) origin.x = p.x;
        if (p.y < origin.y) origin.y = p.y;
    }

      // Then, we orient all of its points relative to the real origin.
    for (Point p : shape) {
       p.x -= origin.x;
      p.y -= origin.y;
    }
    }
```

.....
.....
....
in the main asteroid class . I want to make a polygon which is my ship. How can i put the parameter here?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        Asteroids a = new Asteroids();
        a.repaint();
```

I want to create an object of polygon
I tried like this

```
       Polygon p=new polygon({(0,2),(2,3),(3,1)},(2,3),3);

           p.repaint();
```

I am not taking the parameter correctly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you need to create an array of type `Point` that initializes new `Point` objects, like so:

```
new Point[] {new Point(0,2),new Point(2,3),new Point(3,1)}
```

And then define a new `Point`:

```
new Point(2,3)
```

So your constructor call would look like this:

```
Polygon p = new Polygon(
    new Point[] {new Point(0,2),new Point(2,3),new Point(3,1)},
    new Point(2,3),
    3);
```